# How to make a curved shape with animation for bottom navigation bar on Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, bottom-navigation-bar

How to create bottom navigation bar shape like this on Jetpack Compose?
[image]

[image]